getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError while working on selenium java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest (in module org.seleniumhq.selenium.http) cannot access class dev.failsafe.function.CheckedFunction (in unnamed module @0xc540f5a) because module org.seleniumhq.selenium.http does not read unnamed module @0xc540f5a
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.<clinit>(RetryRequest.java:39)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<clinit>(ClientConfig.java:33)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at Introduction/selenium.SelIntroduction.main(SelIntroduction.java:11)

how to resolved this issue? need help

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
